# Haskell polymorhpism problem in modules extending

Tags: haskell

In Functional programming and Haskell big amount of code is inside functions.

There with if statements (or case):

This is part of the code in some function:

```
case x of
    Apple i -> ...
    Orange i -> ...
    Tomato i -> ....
```

This works fine but I have a question.

How to solve this problem.

In case this code is used in libraries and every developer can add their own types.

Like Meat, Banana and whatever.

In Haskell way all the types should be descriped in this function.

But that's not possible since I don't know what the developers will add.

Since in haskell I dont have methods in object I cannot put the method on the object itself.

How can this problem be solved.

Comment: What you here describe is known as the "Expression problem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem For a solution in Haskell, see https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~tom.schrijvers/Research/talks/lhug2.pdf

Comment: I understood you type all types and what to do. But this not solve the problem. I want more types to be added from outside the module. I create the library, you use it and you can add more types. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: well here we add an extra level of "indirection" such that people can plug in their own type with ADTs.

Comment: Can you describe it with simple sudo code, I dont understand fully monads, functors and etc. Can you describe the main idea - you can use javacsript code if it is appropriate.

Comment: `Apple`, `Orange`, and `Tomato` aren't types; they are data constructors for a *single* type. Developers cannot add their own constructors to an existing type.

Comment: The only thing resembling the problem you describe would be the case where `x` is a value of a type that implements a particular type class, but then you can't pattern match on the value itself; you can only work with it via the methods defined by the type class.

Comment: @user2693928: The idea is basically that instead of making a `data Fruit = Apple | Orange | Tomato`, etc. you make simple types `data Apple = Apple`, `data Orange = Orange`, etc. and then you define a "sum type", so for example `Apple + Orange`, the advantage is that you can define functions over *simply* types. So you "lift" the problem one meta-level up. You can make individual `instance SomeOperation SomeType` objects, and by defining an `instance SomeOperation (a + b)` that performs the "routing", you do not have to care much about that anymore. Haskell itself will make sure it is "routed"

Answer (score 3):

### If this were C++ / Java /etc.

I assume what you mean by all this is the kind of thing OO programmers would solve with a base class and inheritance:

```cpp
class Food {
 private: int i;
 public: virtual void eat() = 0;
};

class Apple: public Food {public: void eat(){crunch(i);}};
class Orange: public Food {public: void eat(){squeek(i);}};
class Tomato: public Food {public: void eat(){splosh(i);}};
...
class Meat: public Food {public: void eat(){malm(i);}};  // added by other developer
...
```

Now, as a general rule, you should keep in mind that such OO classes are different from Haskell classes and are better represented by variant types instead – like you assume in your answer.

### The variant type solution

```
data Food = Apple Int | Orange Int | Tomato Int
eat :: Food -> IO ()
eat (Apple i) = crunch i
eat (Orange i) = squeek i
eat (Tomato i) = splosh i
```

Variant types are usually easier and safer to work with than inheritance hierarchies, precisely because it is exactly *known* what constructors may be encountered.

However, the opposite of an “open world” where different new types of objects *can* be added is definitely a realistic requirement, and this *can* be done with classes

### The typeclass solution / existentials

```
class Edible f where
  eat :: f -> IO ()

data Apple = Apple Int
instance Edible Apple where eat (Apple i) = crunch i
data Orange = Orange Int
instance Edible Orange where eat (Orange i) = squeek i
data Tomato = Tomato Int
instance Edible Tomato where eat (Tomato i) = splosh i
...
data Meat = Meat Int      --- added by other developer
instance Edible Meat where eat (Meat i) = malm i
...
```

The main difference to the variant type is that all the different kinds of `Edible`s actually have different types, so you can't pass around a list containing, say, both `Apple`s and `Orange`s. Well, *you can't comp...*

In OO they're different types as well, however there you can have *base class references* that actually point to a derived object. Haskell doesn't support this directly, but it there is a GHC extension that does: this is called an *existential type*, and can be written either

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Food where
  Food :: Edible f => f -> Food
```

or

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, UnicodeSyntax #-}
data Food = ∀ f . Edible f => Food f
```

Note that this is [somewhat frowned upon](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), only do it if you're sure it's a good idea for your application.

### The “plain-data object” solution

If you don't actually need the type distinction, then you should consider whether you actually need any different labels *at all*. Why not just make it

```
data Food = Food {eat :: IO ()}

apple :: Int -> Food
apple i = Food $ crunch i
orange :: Int -> Food
orange i = Food $ squeek i
tomato :: Int -> Food
tomato i = Food $ splosh i
...
meat :: Int -> Food   -- added by other developer
meat i = Food $ malm i
```

You could still add another field that says what kind of food you're dealing with

```
data Food = Food {foodVariety :: String, eat :: IO ()}

apple :: Int -> Food
apple i = Food "apple" $ crunch i
```

Comment: If this is anti pattern how would I make for example this task. I have some form functions and i have different type of fields (TextField, DropdownField). You can imagine django forms if you like. How would I make another type of field which is not in the framework - for example Autocompleter field or Google Map field. If i use cases in the function i should change the code on the framework. How is the best way to make this work?

Comment: @user2693928 that it's an “anti-pattern” does not mean you _should never use it_. Widgets like `TextField` etc. are indeed something that's often best represented with covariant-polymorphic OO objects, and thus in Haskell with existentials. But if the class that all those objects belong to has only a method like `Int -> IO ()`, then there's not really any use for making different “subclasses” at all – just make the “superclass” a `data Foo = Foo {execFoo :: Int -> IO ()}` structure.

Comment: Ok, how to solve the issue I described. How to make that new types can be added outside the library. So developer A can add Google Map field with own behaviour, developer B can add ColorField for example ?

Comment: That's something you should ask properly in a separate question. Be sure to describe the use-case clear enough, with good, complete code examples.

Comment: The question is exactly about that

Comment: Then it's not written explicitly enough to make that clear. Do ask another question that focuses on a particular use case.